# IIS Reverse proxy and websockets, failed websocket handshake

Tags: iis-7.5, reverse-proxy, socket

I am running a little website using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I've got a node.js application too running on port 3000.

Http calls from the website (client browser) are reverse proxied from `http://example.com/node/whatever` to `http://localhost:3000/whatever`. Everything works fine so far.

The problem is when i try to use socket.io.

I am receiving:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=adb9WRpoMFYRoS0vAAAB' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

I am pretty sure, if i am not wrong, that:

It does forward the initial request to my server as the initial request to a websocket server is a standard HTTP request (with some additional headers). IIS does know about that and simply forwards the request. However, upon receiving the websocket request the websocket server sends a 101 response and switch into websocket mode. IIS does not understand the websocket traffic and it is not able to proxy that.

Is there a trick or solution to configure the reverse proxy for the ws:// adresses?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that WebSocket support was not available in IIS 7.5.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: that was just what I feared, isn't there any workaround on IIS 7.5?